# Change nested loops to stream

Tags: loops, lambda, java-8, java-stream

This is my code. I would like change it to Java 8 style using streams and lambdas. Could you help me?

```
Annotation[][] annotations = joinPoint.getTarget().getClass()
            .getMethod(methodName, signature.getParameterTypes()).getParameterAnnotations();

    for (int i = 0; i < parametersCount; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < annotations[i].length; j++) {
            Annotation annnotation = annotations[i][j];
            if (annnotation.annotationType().isAssignableFrom(Hidden.class)) {
                args.set(i, "***************");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: why would you like to change it?

Comment: arraylist connected with annotations order

Comment: i want to learn this, but when i tried i faild

Comment: Is the args ArrayList empty before this code runs? If it is, you may get exceptions if you try to set the i'th element before setting the `i-1`th element. Also, you may be overwriting the value in args for the same i multiple times. Is that what you want? It's unclear what you are trying to achieve with this code.

Comment: i try change element of list which is conected with element of annotations

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want to achieve but a transition of your code to `Stream` API looks like this:

```
IntStream.range(0, parametersCount).forEach(
    i -> Arrays.stream(annotations[i])
               .filter(a -> a.annotationType().isAssignableFrom(Hidden.class))
               .forEach(annotation -> args.set(i, "***********"))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may write the following way:

```
// create stream of indices
IntStream.range(0, parametersCount) 
         // filter it leaving only those which have at least one Hidden annotation
         .filter(i -> Stream.of(annotations[i])
              .anyMatch(a -> a.annotationType().isAssignableFrom(Hidden.class)))
         // reset the corresponding args
         .forEach(i -> args.set(i, "***********"));
```

Note that this problem is not very well suitable for Stream API due to the following reasons:

1. You are modifying existing data structure. Stream API is the most useful when you operate on immutable data structures (producing something new instead of mutating something existing).
2. You have "parallel" structures: first element of `args` corresponds to the first element of `annotations`, so does the second and so on. This is often not very great code design and standard Stream API is not tailored to support it.